# OpenCart remove option from cart

Tags: opencart

Maybe it's very simple, but I can't get my head around it.

I want to be able to remove an option from an product, and if the product doesn't have anymore options delete the product from the cart.

I've looked at the session value, but I don't see a possibility there:

```
2014-03-14 15:18:30 - Session Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [language] => nl
            [currency] => EUR
            [cart] => Array
                (
                    [63:YToxOntpOjI7YTozOntpOjA7czoxOiIyIjtpOjE7czoyOiI0MSI7aToyO3M6MjoiODAiO319:YTozOntpOjI7YToxOntpOjA7czoxOiIxIjt9aTo0MTthOjE6e2k6MDtzOjE6IjIiO31pOjgwO2E6MTp7aTowO3M6MToiMSI7fX0=] => 1
                )

            [captcha] => dc9c56
            [customer_id] => 1
        )

)
```

I also don't see data in the database that could manipulated easily.

I've looked at the `library/cart.php` file, but it seems that it isn't possible...

(the code there: )

```
public function remove($key) {
    if (isset($this->session->data['cart'][$key])) {
        unset($this->session->data['cart'][$key]);
    }

    $this->data = array();
}
```

So does anybody knows an way ( nice or dirty, don't care ) of how to do this? Maybe receiving every product and delete the one and insert?

Comment: The solution by jx12345 works, but you could do this mainly using the cart methods. What exactly are you trying to achieve, and how are you working out the options to remove (and why are you wanting to remove them)?

Comment: @JayGilford, The solution of jx12345 worked indeed. The point is that i've had to change the cart system a bit ( split 1 product into multiple, so that you've got every option separately with the product. But when you deleted an option, the whole product would be deleted ( so the other options to ). 

So after some changing ( made an new function and referred to that one ), it's working now. But thanks anyway for pointing that one out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
[63:YToxOntpOjI7YTozOntpOjA7czoxOiIyIjtpOjE7czoyOiI0MSI7aToyO3M6MjoiODAiO319:YTozOntpOjI7YToxOntpOjA7czoxOiIxIjt9aTo0MTthOjE6e2k6MDtzOjE6IjIiO31pOjgwO2E6MTp7aTowO3M6MToiMSI7fX0=] => 1
```

is the product_id (63) followed by a serilaized base64_encoded string which represents the product options.

You could decode this and unserialize it into an array, then remove the relevant option, check to see if there are any left, etc...

The getProducts() method of the Cart unserializes and decodes this. Here's the relevant code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $quantity) {
        $is_on_special = 0;
        $product = explode(':', $key);
        $product_id = $product[0];
        $stock = true;

        // Options
        if (isset($product[1])) {
          $options = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
        } else {
          $options = array();
        }
```

Comment: Haha, I was just messing with the unserializing of the string. Thank you for pointing it out. I'll try to make something nice of it.

Comment: happy to help... hope you sort it.

Comment: That won't be the problem. The only problem is: Will it be nice or dirty ^_^